# JavaScript - strip everything before and including a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am relatively new to RegEx and am trying to achieve something which I think may be quite simple for someone more experienced than I.

I would like to construct a snippet in JavaScript which will take an input and strip anything before and including a specific character - in this case, an underscore.

Thus `0_test`, `1_anotherTest`, `2_someOtherTest` would become `test`, `anotherTest` and `someOtherTest`, respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/sV2jN7/2) (*which can only be great if your special character is not known*, see Alex's solution for just `_`):

```
^[^_]*_
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `[^_]*` - Any number of characters other than `_`
- `_` - Underscore

And replace with empty string.

```js
var re = /^[^_]*_/; 
var str = '1_anotherTest';
var subst = ''; 
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

If you have to match before a digit, and you do not know which digit it can be, then the regex way is better (with the `/^[^0-9]*[0-9]/` or `/^\D*\d/` regex).

Comment: However, even if you are new to regex, you should post your own attempts. Please provide them in your question, otherwise, it will be closed, and most probably downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read from its position to the end:

```
var str = "2_someOtherTest";
var res = str.substr(str.indexOf('_') + 1);
```